# What is the maximum number of mutually parallel sides for a convex n-gon?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, polygons

Source:

Mathematical Circles

[image]

The solution to this problem centers around how convex $n$-gons cannot have more than two mutually parallel sides. In other words, each side of a convex $n$-gon can be parallel to another side but no more. For example, a square can have $2$ sets of $2$ mutually parallel sides but we can't have $1$ set of $3$ mutually parallel sides.

---

Here is my informal attempt at proving that a convex $n$-gon can have at most two mutually parallel sides.

Pick a side of an $n$-gon and we'll use that as a reference line. In order to get the angle of any line with reference to the current reference line, it is sufficient to consider the sum of the exterior angles from this reference line up to the desired line. See Figure 1 below.

[image]

In the figure, the angle the side with $C^{\circ}$ makes against the reference base line with the $A^{\circ}$ is equal to $A^{\circ}+B^{\circ}+C^{\circ}$. So for a line to be parallel to the base line, the angle between this line and the base line must be a multiple of $180^\circ$ since $\sin(n*180^\circ) = 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Note that a line having an angle of $0^\circ$ or $360^\circ$ to a reference line is the exact same line as the reference line. Then since the sum of exterior angles of a convex $n$-gon equals $360^{\circ}$, there is only one other option for a mutually parallel line and so a convex $n$-gon can only have at most $2$ mutually parallel lines.

---

Questions:

1) What's the standard way of proving this?

2) What's the quickest way of proving this?

Comment: You are using that the exterior angles are all positive.

Comment: @vonbrand what do you mean?

Comment: Your proof uses the fact that the line is turning the same way as it gets to vertices, On a non-convex polygon this isn't true. Think of three rectangles, two upright and another laid on top. Like a bridge of blocks.

Comment: @vonbrand Would this proof be sufficient if I was just proving it for a convex $n$-gon? Thanks for answering by the way!

Comment: I believe so, but you need the fact that the exterior angles are all positive.